# TSQL (SSMS) conditionally display result of query only conditionally

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Is it possible to display in the results-window of a query in TSQL (SSMS) window conditionally?

For example, display column-header and result of:

> SELECT COUNT(1) AS ourCount FROM [ourDatabase].[dbo].[ourTable]

**only** if it is > 0

NOTE:  We use SQL Server 2008, r-2

This is in the context of a larger system of queries with many results.  I don't want to clutter the results if this particular query has a zero-value.  Of course, the concept could be generalized for other situations.

So I am monitoring the query output, and one could think of the results as an 'alert' to myself (informally).

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool. It doesn't affect how the queries are executed or what they produce. As for filtering data, that's done with the `WHERE` clause of a SELECT statement, or the `HAVING()` clause if you want to filter by an aggregate.

Comment: I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to accomplish the thing you're asking to do? By itself, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Eric Brandt This is in the context of a larger query, where there are many results displayed.  I don't want to clutter the results-window if this value is 0.

Comment: Richard's answer will do that for you, but for troubleshooting purposes, might you not want to know that a table is empty, especially if the expectation is that it won't be? I get the clutter thing, but having a consistent output has readability value, too.

Comment: @Eric Brandt -- I have many things to monitor.  I changed the column and table names, but this is a *real* system, so keeping clutter out is good.

Comment: Sounds like you've thought it through! Run with it.

Comment: @JosephDoggie there are far better options for monitoring than executing a script in SSMS. SSMS itself has several monitoring reports and dashboards. SQL Operations Studio, now called Azure Data Studio, allows you to convert queries to graphs and dashboards *very* easily. Check for example [Customizing Dashboards](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5485/customizing-dashboards-in-sql-operations-studio/). Several addins are already available for monitoring, including one that displays the statistics collected by running Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit

Comment: Thanks -- I currently work on a legacy system.  Btw, I do know how to do SSRS reports and things.  We don't use Azure here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will push the result into a variable, and then only display it if it's greater than zero, you could also use PRINT, etc.

```
DECLARE @Count INT;
SELECT @Count = COUNT(1) AS ourCount FROM [ourDatabase].[dbo].[ourTable];
IF @Count > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Count;
END;
```

If the answer is <= 0 then you will see nothing but the row count in the message part of SSMS.  You can even stop this by adding:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

...at the top of your script, but remember to add:

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Comment: Yes it works.  For those not from the C-family of languages, the ';' is optional in the declare statement.  Does COUNT(1) really work better than COUNT(*)?  I guess so, it certainly is what I use, but I feel it is less readable, lots to say about such a small question!